# What is the difference between empty and void type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

In **Hask**, `Void` (uninhabited type) is the initial object of the category:

```
data Void
```

The unique function is required to show that `Void` is indeed the initial object:

```
absurd :: Void -> a
absurd = absurd
```

The type `Void` is not quite empty because Haskell types have *bottom*, but what is the difference between `Empty` and `Void` types?

Comment: What do you mean, `Empty`? What is the Empty type you are trying to compare Void to?

Comment: @amalloy Empty type is also initial object https://wiki.haskell.org/Hask

Comment: The `Empty` considered on that page is the same as the `Void` from Data.Void.

Comment: The section mentioning `Empty` was added to that Wiki page in 2012. `Data.Void` was only added to *base* in 2015. I guess that if that page were written today the author would have used `Void` instead.

Comment: That is not the definition of `absurd`. The real definition is `absurd x = case x of`.

Comment: @dfeuer I concur. More precisely, I believe it is `absurd x = case x of {}`, since otherwise GHC tries to parse the next line(s) as if they were part of the `case`. We also need to turn on the GHC extension for empty cases.

Comment: @Tcraft Note that the page you mention proves that `Empty` (and, implicitly `Void` which is the same) is _not_ the initial object. Indeed, most categorical properties fail because of bottoms. If we ignore bottoms, then many properties do hold.

Comment: @chi, the braces are optional. Try it yourself!